# Generating x-axis out of csv-data and combine bytes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I try to plot some `.csv`-Files with `pgfplots`. Normally this is no problem but in this case the `.csv`-Files I get do not include data for the x-axis. How can I generate just an increasing number depending on the number of rows in the `.csv`-File? In my MWE below I added this by hand to the data.

Besides that I get the data for the y-axis as two 8 bit values (highbyte and lowbyte) and need to combine them like `value=highbyte*256+lowbyte`. How can I set up this?

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
M1,M2,M3
0,3,50
1,3,51
2,3,49
3,3,50
4,3,48
5,3,52
6,3,50
7,3,51
8,3,49
9,3,50
10,3,48
11,3,52
12,3,48
13,3,50
14,3,51
15,3,49
16,3,48
17,3,51
18,3,49
19,3,52
20,3,50
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, xmin=0]
\addplot table [x index=0, y index=2, col sep=comma]{test.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So basically you want to scale the first column for the x values and compute 256*col1+col3 for the y values.  See \pgfplotstableread and \pgfplotstablecreatecol from the pgfplotstable package.

Comment: The first column is not there in the raw data. It needs to be created with pgfplotstable. I just added it in the MWE to show what the result should be like. I had a look inside pgfplotstable before I asked this question and I found how to create a new column from a list like {0,1,...,20}  but actually I don't know the maximum because it is different every time and a long list of rows so I need to find a way generating this column with the same number of rows as the already existing columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only the last two columns in the table you could use

```
\addplot table [
  x expr=\coordindex,
  y expr=256*\thisrowno{0}+\thisrowno{1},% or y expr=256*\thisrow{M2}+\thisrow{M3},
  col sep=comma
]{test.csv};
```

For the following example I change `ymin` to `780`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
M2,M3
3,50
3,51
3,49
3,50
3,48
3,52
3,50
3,51
3,49
3,50
3,48
3,52
3,48
3,50
3,51
3,49
3,48
3,51
3,49
3,52
3,50
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=780, xmin=0]
\addplot table [
  x expr=\coordindex,
  y expr=256*\thisrowno{0}+\thisrowno{1},% or y expr=256*\thisrow{M2}+\thisrow{M3},
  col sep=comma
]{test.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems that is not necessary to use pgfplotstable. This two easy commands do exactly what I want.